# Remove/Hide SHAPE.STArea() & SHAP.STLength() fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase

Is there a way to hide SHAPE.STArea() & SHAP.STLength() fields in feature classes in an SDE GDB?  I'm working with a client who says that these fields were not in any feature class in the GDB and now all the sudden these fields are in their featureclasses.  I know that you can't delete these fields so if there is no way to remove them is there anything that would cause these fields to appear when they previously weren't visible when looking at the attribute table?  Working with ArcCatalog 10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add feature classes into ArcMap map document they become layers. You can define which fields will be visible for the layer in the Layer Properties window or directly in the Attribute table window. It is hard to guess, but they might have re-added feature classes and the settings they had for layers were updated.

Esri help page: [Setting whether fields are visible in a table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Setting_whether_fields_are_visible_in_a_table/005s0000003q000000/)

> **Steps:**
>
> Open the table; Right-click the field heading and click Turn Field Off.
>
> Another quick way of turning off a field from the Table window is to hold down the CTRL key and double-click the field heading. To turn
>   all the fields on again, choose the Turn All Fields On command from
>   the Table Options menu.
>
> You can open the Layer Properties or Table Properties dialog box and
>   use the Fields tab to set field visibility.

If you have multiple map documents, then consider using arcpy to iterate the layers and hide those fields. There is `[setVisible][2]` method on the `FieldInfo` class.

If you have access to the DBMS, you can consider creating [spatial views](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002q000000r3000000) which would exclude those fields you don't want to show. Be aware though that the views will be available for read-only access.